# Setting Dojo Mobile Switch to change the value shown in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

So I have a problem with the Dojo switch which is really annoying! I hope someone can help me out from wracking my brains over and over with this (and it's probably something simple that I'm not seeing).

Basically, I want to run an if statement to determine whether the switch should be 'on' or 'off' when the user loads the page in question. That sounds easy enough, so here's what I tried to do:

```
document.getElementById('reqPasswordSettingToggle').value = 'on';
```

So that doesn't work because at run time, the id gets disattached from the switch and so it doesn't know what value it's setting to 'on'. So, I thought the next bit of code would work:

```
document.getElementsByName("passwordSwitch").value = "off";
```

At run time, the switch does have the name available, and this legal manner of accessing the name should work. It doesn't. I printed some debug from my if statement and it tells me it's successfully changed the value, but that is not reflected on the screen. Why? I hope someone will know the answer to that!

If you need any more information let me know, but this is simply an attempt to set this mobile switch to 'on' or 'off' based on a simple if statement in JS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise that you could use the dijit notation to deal with this:

```
var widget = dijit.byId("switch");
widget.set("value", "on");
```

That works a charm!